how to get rid of circular dependencies in C
I'm new to C and I'm stuck on this problem.  In C# doing something like this is perfectly ok but in C the compiler works different and it needs to know the type definitions before hand.
struct FN;

typedef struct {
    void (*create) (FN *fn);
} Window;

typedef struct {
    Window window;
} FN;

Is there some kind of C trick with pointers etc that I can use to get it working?  I'm trying to create like a "manager" class where I can call functions on my modules and then just pass the manager around where needed.

It's almost correct code. FN *fn -> struct FN *fn. Because in C (unlike C++) you can't just type FN for a struct which wasn't declared without typedef. Best practices in C is to always typedef structs (see Are there technical reasons to pick one struct coding style over the other?). But in this case simply move the FN definition above the Window one and drop the forward declaration.

In the shown code you first declare a structure (not a type) named FN. Then later you redefine FN as a type-name. Besides this conflicting declarations you can't use FN as a type because it's initially not a type-name.
If you can live with FN being a structure tag name you could just use
typedef struct {
    void (*create) (struct FN *fn);
} Window;

struct FN
{
    Window window;
};

If you want to make FN a type-name then declare the structure but define the type-name:
typedef struct FN FN;  // Yes, structures and type-names can have the same name

typedef struct {
    void (*create) (FN *fn);
} Window;

struct FN
{
    Window window;
};


@user2980746 Re "I don't understand it", You can have a pointer to a structure type before without first declaring the the structure type. So, void f(struct FN *fn); struct FN { ... }; (which uses a structure type) succeeds where void f(FN *fn); typedef struct { ... } FN; (which doesn't) fails.

@ikegami - thx for reply.  ya I get that part.  what I meant was the typedef struct FN FN; part.  Why is FN needed twice?  I know it's so we can set a struct without saying "struct" before it but I guess it's just a quirk of the language.

@user2980746 You could use any other name for the struct, like typedef struct MyStructure FN;, but then you have to remember to name the structure MyStructure when you define it. I also recommend you take some time to learn and understand the difference between declarations and definitions.

Re "Why is FN needed twice?", It creates type FN to be an alias for the type struct FN. Here I replaced every struct FN with A, and every FN with B

Just write
typedef struct FN FN;

typedef struct {
    void (*create) (FN *fn);
} Window;

struct FN
{
    Window window;
};

As for your code then the structure
struct FN;

and the unnamed structure with the alias name FN
typedef struct 
{
    Window window;
} 
FN;

are two different type specifiers.
